# how to show multiple videos in the same page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is my code

```
class SecondVideosItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final AllVideoResponse videoResponse;
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;

  SecondVideosItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.videoResponse,
      required this.videoPlayerController})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondVideosItemState createState() => _SecondVideosItemState();
}
```

this is init state

```
class _SecondVideosItemState extends State<SecondVideosItem> {
  late Future<void> futureController;
  PrefsHelper prefsHelper = PrefsHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        getBaseURLVideos(mediaPath: widget.videoResponse.mediaPath),
        videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true));
    widget.videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value) {
      widget.videoPlayerController.play();
      widget.videoPlayerController.setVolume(0);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }
```

and this is widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
     
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
              ),
              elevation: 0,
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: VideoPlayer(widget.videoPlayerController),
                  ),
                 
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code
i am trying to create page with multiple videos run with the same time
i added listview then i call this class

i am trying to do page like this

[image]

**when i scroll down videos disappear and  also when i refresh page the same thing happen**

Answer (score 0):

You try using     `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on state class. like

```dart
class _SecondVideosItemState extends State<SecondVideosItem> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  
  ....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);//important
```

Comment: not working when i added this code and request another page  all videos disappeared

Comment: any error on console ?

Comment: ```
ernal(20372):       ... 10 more
E/flutter (20372): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error, index=0, format=Format(1, null, null, video/avc, avc1.64001F, -1, null, [464, 848, 30.0], [-1, -1]), format_supported=YES, null, null)

Comment: You can try SingleChildScrolView but it is not that optimized for this,

Comment: i am using listview.builder with controller to know if user swip to end of screen
the problem happen again when i press hot reload